# xcode connecting distribution provisioning profile to development certificate

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning

Im using xcode and I want to upload my app. In order to upload I need to build my app with the distribution provisioning profile. I have a valid distribution provisioning profile but when i try to build xcode gives my this error:

Code Sign error: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching the profile 'Dodge    Cars Free Distribution1' and identity 'iPhone Developer: Rajeev Arora (4DL7HDW3F2)'

What i understand is this means xcode is trying to check the validity of my distribution provisioning profile with a development certificate. Obviously this wouldn't work. How can i get xcode to recognize that my provisioning profile is for distribution? I've tried making a new distribution profile with no results.

EDIT

I found a solution I guess. I tried building with one of my old provisioning profiles and it worked

Answer (score 4):

If I can remember correctly, these are the steps needed to be done to use the Distribution provisioning profile:

1. Import the Distribution certificate into Keychain Access
2. Dragged the Distribution Provisioning Profile into the Xcode icon on your Dock
3. Set in Build Settings to use iPhone Distribution in the Code Signing section/field

Edit from comments: You should not press the Run button, as it will always give an error. You should click Product > Archive from the menu. The archive of your project should show up in the Organizer window > Archives tab. From there, you should be able to Submit your app.

Comment: Oh wait, something came across my mind. Did you press the Run button or did you choose Product > Build for Archiving or Product > Archive?

Comment: Ah, you should not press the Run button as it always gives an error. I have updated my answer.